# MongoDB find documents with duplicate field in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a very large "customer" database of documents.  Each of those documents has an array called "activities".  Inside that array are objects with multiple fields. One of those fields is called types, so activities.types. I would like to just get a count of how many documents have more than 1 activity where the type field is "postcards". Basically when we send out marketing material it saves each one as an activity and I want to know how many customers have received more than one postcard. I've tried aggregates like the below code but that doesn't specify postcards or how many documents meet this criteria. I don't need the actual documents.  Just a count.

```
db.getCollection('contacts').aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$activities" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        same_type: "$activities.type"
      },
      sum: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $match: { sum: { $gt: 1 } } },
])
```

Comment: 'I would like to just get a count of how many documents have more than 1 activity where the type field is "postcards".' and "...I want to know all the customers that have received more than one postcard."  Do you want to know both, or only one?

Comment: I'm sorry that wasn't very clear.  I just need a count of how many contacts have more than one activity where the type is 'postcard'. I'll edit the original post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get the total count of customers who received more than one `"postcards"` contact.

```js
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "activities.types": "postcards"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "postcardsCount": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$activities",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {"$eq": ["$$this.types", "postcards"]},
              {"$add": ["$$value", 1]},
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {"$gt": ["$postcardsCount", 1]}
    }
  },
  {"$count": "totalCount"}
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "totalCount": 23
  }
]
```

Try it one [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/en-HTpwtfJk).